# NodeJS process.env not reading updated OPENAI_API_KEY

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, terminal, environment-variables, openai-api

So, working on Ubuntu 14, I changed my OPENAI_API_KEY and put my change into my NodeJS project .env file. Previously everything worked well. But now openai API responded with bad key error. So it turned out that my program was sending it the previous API key, despite I changed it in my .env file.
I tried to set it up manually with

```
process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY=abcdefghij123
```

and it worked, but as soon as I removed it from code (since it would end up on Git which is a big no no), it was reading old API key again.

Answer (score 0):

1st part of solution to this was to print entire process.env like

```
console.log('My process.env', process.env)
```

This discovered A LOT more variables than just 3-4 variables in my NodeJS project .env, like JAVA_HOME, CATALINA_HOME, USER, DESKTOP_SESSION... etc. It became obvious that process.env also was reading external variables.
Then, I remembered that some time ago I exported OPENAI_API_KEY with

```
export OPENAI_API_KEY=sk-iXefsjfijsifjsifjsifjsifj
```

so the next step was to try to unset it. So I did

```
unset OPENAI_API_KEY
```

restarted my NodeJS app, and voila, it was reading my new API key from my .env file!

---

EDIT: Ok, faced the same issue again. The problem now is that 'unset' unsets the key for the current session only.
So I decided to be a little more persistent with this and I did, in my root:

```
cat .bash* | grep OPENAI_API_KEY
```

which discovered that the following line was really somewhere there:

```
export OPENAI_API_KEY=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
```

It turned out in the end that I didn't pay enough attention to my .bashrc file, where the export was at the bottom of it.

Moral of the story: don't trust your eyes, trust terminal commands.